# help needed with mysql DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get names out of a mysql table for an autocomplete (jquery ui). There are duplicate names and I don't want to show them in the suggestions. I also need to select other columns in the same query. is this possible? I'm using this query atm but there are still duplicate "s_name" returned..

```
SELECT DISTINCT s_name, s_time, s_auto, s_inout FROM testtable where s_name like '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) . "%'
```

Comment: What should happen when names have multiple different `s_time, s_auto, s_inout` values? What do you want shown in those rows?

Comment: So, if there are two (or more) rows with same `s_name` what should the query return for `s_time` and other columns? Which of the two (or more) values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GROUP BY` (man page)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html):

```
SELECT s_name, s_time, s_auto, s_inout 
FROM testtable where s_name like '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) . "%'
GROUP BY s_name
```

Comment: but be aware the contents of `s_time, s_auto, s_inout` are undefined.

Comment: Agreed there are caveats and thank you for pointing them out, but this should solve the issue in this case I think.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans glad it works. Please mark this as the answer and give it an upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT will apply to the entire row - not just the column you stick it in front of.  Could you just apply the filtering in PHP after obtaining the data from MySQL?